# Unity Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors, scripting

I know this is a well-known question. But I don't know what to do.
[image]

(Open the image in a new tab for better clarity)

That script FastIKFabric.cs is working perfectly (moreover it's from asset store) and as you can see in the inspector it does not have any `using UnityEditor;`. The line 250 is the last one from that script and the `}` is closed properly. As I said, the script does not have any errors.

What can I do? Thanks in advance for any answer! :)

Here is the script:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
#endif
using UnityEngine;

namespace DitzelGames.FastIK
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fabrik IK Solver
    /// </summary>
    public class FastIKFabric : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Chain length of bones
        /// </summary>
        public int ChainLength = 2;

        /// <summary>
        /// Target the chain should bent to
        /// </summary>
        public Transform Target;
        public Transform Pole;

        /// <summary>
        /// Solver iterations per update
        /// </summary>
        [Header("Solver Parameters")]
        public int Iterations = 10;

        /// <summary>
        /// Distance when the solver stops
        /// </summary>
        public float Delta = 0.001f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Strength of going back to the start position.
        /// </summary>
        [Range(0, 1)]
        public float SnapBackStrength = 1f;


        protected float[] BonesLength; //Target to Origin
        protected float CompleteLength;
        protected Transform[] Bones;
        protected Vector3[] Positions;
        protected Vector3[] StartDirectionSucc;
        protected Quaternion[] StartRotationBone;
        protected Quaternion StartRotationTarget;
        protected Transform Root;


        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Awake()
        {
            Init();
        }

        void Init()
        {
            //initial array
            Bones = new Transform[ChainLength + 1];
            Positions = new Vector3[ChainLength + 1];
            BonesLength = new float[ChainLength];
            StartDirectionSucc = new Vector3[ChainLength + 1];
            StartRotationBone = new Quaternion[ChainLength + 1];

            //find root
            Root = transform;
            for (var i = 0; i <= ChainLength; i++)
            {
                if (Root == null)
                    throw new UnityException("The chain value is longer than the ancestor chain!");
                Root = Root.parent;
            }

            //init target
            if (Target == null)
            {
                Target = new GameObject(gameObject.name + " Target").transform;
                SetPositionRootSpace(Target, GetPositionRootSpace(transform));
            }
            StartRotationTarget = GetRotationRootSpace(Target);


            //init data
            var current = transform;
            CompleteLength = 0;
            for (var i = Bones.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Bones[i] = current;
                StartRotationBone[i] = GetRotationRootSpace(current);

                if (i == Bones.Length - 1)
                {
                    //leaf
                    StartDirectionSucc[i] = GetPositionRootSpace(Target) - GetPositionRootSpace(current);
                }
                else
                {
                    //mid bone
                    StartDirectionSucc[i] = GetPositionRootSpace(Bones[i + 1]) - GetPositionRootSpace(current);
                    BonesLength[i] = StartDirectionSucc[i].magnitude;
                    CompleteLength += BonesLength[i];
                }

                current = current.parent;
            }



        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void LateUpdate()
        {
            ResolveIK();
        }

        private void ResolveIK()
        {
            if (Target == null)
                return;

            if (BonesLength.Length != ChainLength)
                Init();

            //Fabric

            //  root
            //  (bone0) (bonelen 0) (bone1) (bonelen 1) (bone2)...
            //   x--------------------x--------------------x---...

            //get position
            for (int i = 0; i < Bones.Length; i++)
                Positions[i] = GetPositionRootSpace(Bones[i]);

            var targetPosition = GetPositionRootSpace(Target);
            var targetRotation = GetRotationRootSpace(Target);

            //1st is possible to reach?
            if ((targetPosition - GetPositionRootSpace(Bones[0])).sqrMagnitude >= CompleteLength * CompleteLength)
            {
                //just strech it
                var direction = (targetPosition - Positions[0]).normalized;
                //set everything after root
                for (int i = 1; i < Positions.Length; i++)
                    Positions[i] = Positions[i - 1] + direction * BonesLength[i - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Positions.Length - 1; i++)
                    Positions[i + 1] = Vector3.Lerp(Positions[i + 1], Positions[i] + StartDirectionSucc[i], SnapBackStrength);

                for (int iteration = 0; iteration < Iterations; iteration++)
                {
                    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNoX65PRehA
                    //back
                    for (int i = Positions.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (i == Positions.Length - 1)
                            Positions[i] = targetPosition; //set it to target
                        else
                            Positions[i] = Positions[i + 1] + (Positions[i] - Positions[i + 1]).normalized * BonesLength[i]; //set in line on distance
                    }

                    //forward
                    for (int i = 1; i < Positions.Length; i++)
                        Positions[i] = Positions[i - 1] + (Positions[i] - Positions[i - 1]).normalized * BonesLength[i - 1];

                    //close enough?
                    if ((Positions[Positions.Length - 1] - targetPosition).sqrMagnitude < Delta * Delta)
                        break;
                }
            }

            //move towards pole
            if (Pole != null)
            {
                var polePosition = GetPositionRootSpace(Pole);
                for (int i = 1; i < Positions.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    var plane = new Plane(Positions[i + 1] - Positions[i - 1], Positions[i - 1]);
                    var projectedPole = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(polePosition);
                    var projectedBone = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(Positions[i]);
                    var angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(projectedBone - Positions[i - 1], projectedPole - Positions[i - 1], plane.normal);
                    Positions[i] = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, plane.normal) * (Positions[i] - Positions[i - 1]) + Positions[i - 1];
                }
            }

            //set position & rotation
            for (int i = 0; i < Positions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == Positions.Length - 1)
                    SetRotationRootSpace(Bones[i], Quaternion.Inverse(targetRotation) * StartRotationTarget * Quaternion.Inverse(StartRotationBone[i]));
                else
                    SetRotationRootSpace(Bones[i], Quaternion.FromToRotation(StartDirectionSucc[i], Positions[i + 1] - Positions[i]) * Quaternion.Inverse(StartRotationBone[i]));
                SetPositionRootSpace(Bones[i], Positions[i]);
            }
        }

        private Vector3 GetPositionRootSpace(Transform current)
        {
            if (Root == null)
                return current.position;
            else
                return Quaternion.Inverse(Root.rotation) * (current.position - Root.position);
        }

        private void SetPositionRootSpace(Transform current, Vector3 position)
        {
            if (Root == null)
                current.position = position;
            else
                current.position = Root.rotation * position + Root.position;
        }

        private Quaternion GetRotationRootSpace(Transform current)
        {
            //inverse(after) * before => rot: before -> after
            if (Root == null)
                return current.rotation;
            else
                return Quaternion.Inverse(current.rotation) * Root.rotation;
        }

        private void SetRotationRootSpace(Transform current, Quaternion rotation)
        {
            if (Root == null)
                current.rotation = rotation;
            else
                current.rotation = Root.rotation * rotation;
        }

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            var current = this.transform;
            for (int i = 0; i < ChainLength && current != null && current.parent != null; i++)
            {
                var scale = Vector3.Distance(current.position, current.parent.position) * 0.1f;
                //Handles.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(current.position, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, current.parent.position - current.position), new Vector3(scale, Vector3.Distance(current.parent.position, current.position), scale));
                //Handles.color = Color.green;
                //Handles.DrawWireCube(Vector3.up * 0.5f, Vector3.one);
                current = current.parent;
            }
        }
#endif

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 2 cents. A long answer just to illustrate the problem and make it easier for others to see.

---

Take a minute and think about the preprocessor directive (`#if UNITY_EDITOR`), so, if we are inside/using the UnityEditor the code inside the directives (`#if...#endif`) will be active.

So since we have:

```
// previous code ...

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            var current = this.transform;
            for (int i = 0; i < ChainLength && current != null && current.parent != null; i++)
            {
                // ...code...
            }
        }
#endif

        // rest of the code ...
        private void LikeAnotherMethod() 
        {
            ....
        }
```

While we are in UNITY_EDITOR will be equal to;

```
// previous code ...

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            var current = this.transform;
            for (int i = 0; i < ChainLength && current != null && current.parent != null; i++)
            {
                // ...code...
            }
        }

        // rest of the code ...
        private void LikeAnotherMethod() 
        {
            ....
        }
```

But, if we are not on UnityEditor's world (like on an Android, iOS, or MacOSX game) everything inside those preprocessor directives will be gone.

So, in our case;

```
// previous code ...

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
// nope        var current = this.transform;
// nope        for (int i = 0; i < ChainLength && current != null && current.parent != null; i++)
// nope         {
// nope             // ...code...
// nope         }
// nope }
#endif

        // rest of the code ...
        private void LikeAnotherMethod() 
        {
            ....
        }
```

which is the same as;

```
// previous code ...

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {


        // rest of the code ...
        private void LikeAnotherMethod() 
        {
            ....
        }
```

So in the last block of code is easier to see that before the `//rest of the code` a `{` is missing. This is the cause of the problem. 
VisualStudio (or other IDEs will not complain in the meanwhile because inside UnityEditor world everything is ok, but once you are building the app it will fail.)

---

A possible fix will be to move the #endif preprocessor directive one line up:

```
// previous code ...

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            var current = this.transform;
            for (int i = 0; i < ChainLength && current != null && current.parent != null; i++)
            {
                // ...code...
            }
#endif
        }


        // rest of the code ...
        private void LikeAnotherMethod() 
        {
            ....
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how it works with that ```{``` :).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you, the compiler doesn't lie. Perhaps you closed it properly, but did you save the script in visual studio before rebuilding??

Comment: The script in visual studio does not have any error, vs should underline but nothing is underlined. And also says 0 errors and 0 warnings in vs. I've used this script a time ago and at the time it worked. I didn't change it at all because it's from the asset store and it worked perfectly.

Comment: post the full script please

Comment: where, in the question?

Comment: yea sometimes vs doesn't catch everything i just wanna check it

Comment: you are missing a curley just put one at the bottom to close off the namespace and it should work, just from glancing at it

Comment: you commented off         void OnDrawGizmos()
        { and left a curley, i'm guessing thats where you got an extra

Comment: at what line do you say I commented off?

Comment: the OnDrawGizmos() you left an extra curley

Comment: I've deleted the whole function (because anyway I see that I do not use it) and just now I saw the problem. It was in another script. I have more than 30-40 scripts and I started to verify each one of them and one was getting me an error. Thanks a lot for your patience, but idk why the unity compiler said that the error was in that script when it was in another one. And the actual error showed up only after I deleted the OnDrawGizmos(). Thanks again! :)